# Heat transfer and Stefan-Boltzmann law and black body radiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, thermal-radiation, radiation

can there exist a black body (theoretically) which has a cavity in it I don't mean Fery's black body I am referring to a black body which is made of a MATERIAL which has the property to emit and absorb electromagnetic waves of all wavelengths.

If it does exist then obviously it will emit radiation from both the inner and outer surface and the total radiation power emitted by the surfaces will depend on the surface areas of the inner and outer surface.

Now let us have energy radiating spherical machine and we tightly fix 2 thin((thin enough that their outer and inner radii are the same)) shells of black bodies concentrically

Let's say that this system has reached its steady state

and now Q is the energy of radiation emitted by the central sphere within a given time interval,
all of this will be absorbed by the black body which has this sphere in it and it will radiate radiations having energy Q/2 from both of its surfaces now that the other outermost blackbody absorbed Q/2 worth of radiation it will further emit Q/4 worth of radiation from both of its surfaces

now if we add the total radiation absorbed or emitted by each black body you can see that the blackbody in the middle of the central sphere and the outer black body it is irradiating Q/2 worth of radiation out of it from both of its surfaces which makes Q worth radiation being emitted out and it absorbs Q worth of radiation from the central sphere and also absorbs Q/4 worth of radiation from the outermost blackbody.

You can see that there is a net Q/4 worth of radiation absorbed by the black body that further when the system has achieved a steady state and that contradicts.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my thought?

Comment: When you calculated Q/2, you ignored the radiation from the outer sphere to the inner sphere. Then, when you didn’t ignore that radiation, you found a contradiction. It shouldn’t be surprising that a calculation that doesn’t incorporate some factor can’t be used to determine that factor.